# Lucene: queries and docs with multiple fields

Tags: java, lucene

I have a collection of documents consisting of several fields, and I need to perform queries with several terms coming from multiple fields.

What do you suggest me to use ? MultiFieldQueryParser or MultiPhraseQuery ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about BooleanQuery?

http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_2/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/BooleanQuery.html

Comment: I'm actually studying it right now. It seems the best option, using BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD parameter for each field. Also, I was thinking if I should use multiple TermQueries per field (one for each term in each field), or should I use PhraseQuery.

Comment: One of the fields are a list of tags, so I guess I need to use a list of TermQueries having the same field.

Answer (score 1):

#### Choice of Analyzer

First of all, watch out which analyzer you are using. I was stumped for a while only to realise that the StandardAnalyzer filters out common words like 'the' and 'a'. This is a problem when your field has the value 'A'. You might want to consider the KeywordAnalyzer:

[See this post around the analyzer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9071806/231860)

```
// Create an analyzer:
// NOTE: We want the keyword analyzer so that it doesn't strip or alter any terms:
// In our example, the Standard Analyzer removes the term 'A' because it is a common English word.
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/9071806/231860
KeywordAnalyzer analyzer = new KeywordAnalyzer();
```

#### Query Parser

Next, you can either create your query using the QueryParser:

[See this post around overriding the default operator.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9084178/231860)

```
// Create a query parser without a default field in this example (the first argument):
QueryParser queryParser = new QueryParser("", analyzer);

// Optionally, set the default operator to be AND (we leave it the default OR):
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/9084178/231860
// queryParser.setDefaultOperator(QueryParser.Operator.AND);

// Parse the query:
Query multiTermQuery = queryParser.parse("field_name1:\"field value 1\" AND field_name2:\"field value 2\"");
```

#### Query API

Or you can achieve the same by constructing the query yourself using their API:

[See this tutorial around creating the BooleanQuery.](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-combine-queries-with-a-boolean-query.html)

```
BooleanQuery multiTermQuery = new BooleanQuery();
multiTermQuery.add(new TermQuery(new Term("field_name1", "field value 1")), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
multiTermQuery.add(new TermQuery(new Term("field_name2", "field value 2")), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
```

#### Delete the Documents that Match the Query

Then we finally pass the query to the writer to delete documents that match the query:

[See my answer here, related to this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43953057/231860)

[See the answer to this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4851313/231860)

```
// Remove the document by using a multi key query:
// http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-combine-queries-with-a-boolean-query.html
writer.deleteDocuments(multiTermQuery);
```