# Lucene search using StopWords in StandardAnalyzer

Tags: lucene, lucene.net, analyzer, stop-words, standardanalyzer

I have the following issue using Lucene.NET 3.0.3.

My project analyze Documents using StandardAnalyzer with StopWord-List (combined german and english words).
While searching I create my searchterm by hand and parse it using MultiFieldQueryParser. The Parser is initialized with the same analyzer as indexing documents.
The parsed search query initialized a BooleanQuery. The BooleanQuery and a TopScoreDocCollector search in the Lucene index with IndexSearcher.
My code looks like:

```
using (StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30, roxConnectionTools.getServiceInstance<ISearchIndexService>().GetStopWordList()))
{
    ...
    MultiFieldQueryParser parser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30, searchFields, analyzer);
    parser.MultiTermRewriteMethod = MultiTermQuery.SCORING_BOOLEAN_QUERY_REWRITE;
    parser.AllowLeadingWildcard = true;
    ...
    Query searchQuery = parser.Parse(searchStringBuilder.ToString().Trim);
    ...
    BooleanQuery boolQuery = new BooleanQuery();
    boolQuery.Add(searchQuery, Occur.MUST);
    ...
    TopScoreDocCollector scoreCollector = TopScoreDocCollector.Create(SearchServiceTools.MAX_SCORE_COLLECTOR_SIZE, true);
    ...
    searcher.Search(boolQuery, scoreCollector);
    ScoreDoc[] scoreDocs = scoreCollector.TopDocs().ScoreDocs;
}
```

If I index a document field with value "Test- und Produktivumgebung" I can´t find this document by searching this term.
I get results if I correct the search term to "Test- Produktivumgebung".
The word "und" is in my StopWord-List.

My search query looks like the following:
    Manually generated search query: ***(+*Test* +*und* +*Produktivumgebung*)***
    Parsed search query: ***+(title:*Test*) +(title:*und*) +(title:*Produktivumgebung*)***

Why I can´t find the document searching for "Test- und Produktivumgebung"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wildcard Queries are not analyzed (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9066347/lucene-multi-word-phrases-as-search-terms), for an example).  Since you are (if I understand correctly), interpreting the query `"Test- und Produktivumgebung"` to `(+*Test* +*und* +*Produktivumgebung*)`, the analyzer is not used for any of those wildcard queries, and stop words will not be eliminated.

If you eliminate the step that performs that translation, the query `"Test- und Produktivumgebung"` should be parsed to a phrase query and analyzed, and should work just fine.  Another reason to eliminate that step, is that applying a leading wildcard to every term will cause your performance to become very poor.  That's why leading wildcards must be manually enabled, because it is generally a bad idea to use them.